# iOS run compiled code written in other language?

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering, let's say I write a very simple program in some language that isn't supported by iOS. It's the kind of executable one would run from a command line, in that it takes bytes as input and produces bytes as output.

So if I compiled that program to iOS machine code, could I include it as a resource in the app bundle of an app written in Swift? I'd like to then be able to run it from the Swift code, passing it an array of bytes and receiving an array of bytes, which I could then assign to a variable in Swift.

To be clear, this is a theoretical question: I just want to know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Comment: Are you including approval by Apple to have it available in their AppStore?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary for the answer to be App Store friendly.

Comment: There is a non-sequitur in your question. You ask "if I compiled this program to iOS machine code.."; I guess you mean compiled it to ARM machine code in a linkage format that iOS can understand.  If you can do that then your language is "supported" by iOS. It isn't iOS that supports languages. It is languages that have a cross-compiler for iOS. E.g. Xamarin lets you compile C# code for iOS. Apple didn't do anything to iOS to support this. The Xamarin folk had to do all of the work.

Comment: @Paulw11 Well of course. But my theoretical binary has no GUI. I want write the GUI layer in pure UIKit.

Comment: Having a GUI is nothing to do with it. You can link a library into your project written in any language as long as the binary format is compatible. I could write a library in C# and link it to a project where the UI portion was written in Swift because Xamarin provides a compiler that outputs compatible binaries

Comment: So I can just treat the binary like any old 3rd party Cocoa Touch framework?